# No puedo enviar correos en python(spyder)

Tags: python, spyder

Tengo un problema con enviar correos en python. Originalmente tengo un script que cancela ordenes de una pagina web automáticamente, una vez cancela las ordenes las exporta a un excel y un contador cuenta cuantas cancelaciones exitosas se hicieron y debe enviar un correo de cuantas se realizaron, ese script no corre, me aparece un error en el envio y no me entrega el error exacto por lo cual hice otro script que solo envíe un correo para ver que pasaba, pero me entrega el mismo error sin dar detalle. Me podrían ayudar con sugerencias porfavor! Dejo el script de prueba que solamente envía el correo:

```
import smtplib
from email.message import EmailMessage


def enviar_correo(destinatario, asunto, mensaje, remitente, contraseña, servidor_smtp, 
puerto_smtp):
# Crear el objeto EmailMessage
correo = EmailMessage()
correo['Hola hola'] = asunto
correo['pabarrazaeom@gmail.com'] = remitente
correo['pascalbarra@hotmail.com'] = destinatario
correo.set_content(mensaje)

try:
    # Establecer la conexión con el servidor SMTP
    servidor = smtplib.SMTP_SSL(servidor_smtp, puerto_smtp)

    # Iniciar sesión en el servidor SMTP
    servidor.login(remitente, contraseña)

    # Enviar el correo electrónico
    servidor.send_message(correo)

    # Cerrar la conexión con el servidor SMTP
    servidor.quit()

    print("El correo electrónico se ha enviado correctamente.")
except Exception as e:
    print("Error al enviar el correo electrónico:", str(e))

# Ejemplo de uso
destinatario = 'pascalbarra@hotmail.com'
asunto = 'Hola'
mensaje = '¡Hola! Esto es un correo de prueba.'

remitente = 'pabarrazaeom@gmail.com'
contraseña = 'czpvl'
servidor_smtp = 'smtp.gmail.com'
puerto_smtp = 465

enviar_correo(destinatario, asunto, mensaje, remitente, contraseña, servidor_smtp, 
puerto_smtp)


Lo que me arroja en la consola
runfile('C:/Users/pbarrazae/Desktop/codigo para correos.py', 
wdir='C:/Users/pbarrazae/Desktop')
Error al enviar el correo electrónico: {}
```

Comment: Por cuestiones de seguridad, desde hace tiempo Gmail ya no soporta autenticación simple con usuario y contraseña. Hay que autorizar una aplicación desde la consola de Google y luego usar el password generado en el código. Mira [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71008714/1545868) - en inglés.